# jquery find h2 tags and append into div

Tags: jquery, html, find, append

I'm trying to write a bit of jquery which finds all h2 tags inside a div (.content), then appends each one into another div (.intro).

So far I have this:

```
var h2 = $(".content").find("h2");
$(h2).each(function() {
  $(this).append(".intro");
});
```

But it's not working.. if someone could help me out, that'd be great :)

Comment: anyway is not clear if you want clone or just move to!

Comment: A common mistake is to use `each()` when there's no need. When you have a set of elements (like with your `find()` results), you can call functions on the set all at once without the need to iterate over the elements and act on each one individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var h2 = $('h2', '.content');
$('.intro').append(h2);
```

No need to use `each()`. jQuery has something called "implicit iteration" where you can act on the entire set at once. So you can grab them all, and append them all at the same time.

Or did you want to append a copy of them?

If so, try:

```
var h2 = $('h2', '.content');
$('.intro').append(h2.clone());
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or use a single line version:

```
$('.intro').append($('h2', '.content').clone());​
```

(of course, remove `.clone()` if you don't need to copy them.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method.

```
var h2 = $(".content").find("h2");
$(h2).each(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo($(".intro"));
});
```

Edit: Just noticed that `appendTo` was moving the `h2` tags, so incase that is not desired, added the call to `clone()`.

Answer (score 2):

Could use children(), something like...

```
$('.content').children('h2').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($('.intro'));
});
```